# How to generate JSONArray properly from Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to generate that kind of JSON String using Java (purpose : flot for Android) :

```
{
"data": [[1999, 1], [2000, 0.23], [2001, 3], [2002, 4], [2003, 1.3], [2004, 2.5], [2005, 2.0], [2006, 3.1], [2007, 2.9], [2008, 0.9]]
}
```

To do this, I'm using JSONArray like this :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put("[1999, 1]");
jsonArray.put("[2000, 0.23]");
jsonArray.put("[2001, 3]");
...
```

But the only result I get is this :

```
["[1999, 1]","[2000, 0.23]","[2001, 3]",..."[2008, 0.9]"]
```

How Can I remove quote between brackets ? Can I type the items of my array ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is just adding Strings to the array. You don't want Strings, you want nested arrays. So you have to work with nested JSONArray objects:

Here's the standard way:

```
JSONArray nested1 = new JSONArray();
nested1.put(1999);
nested1.put(1);
jsonArray.put(nested1);
```

Or, [simpler](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
jsonArray.put(new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(1999, 1)));
```

Or, [even simpler](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#put%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
jsonArray.put(Arrays.asList(1999, 1));
// or use an int array:
jsonArray.put(new int[]{1999, 1});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick an exhaustive answer ! This works just great!